# Tennouji Yuusha?

Tags: rewrite

In episode 4 of Rewrite minute 6:50-6:55, during the flash back between Tennouji Koutarou and Nakatsu Shizuru, Koutarou introduced his name as Tennouji Yuusha. When Shizuru called him Yuusha-senpai, he corrected it into Tennouji Koutarou.

In Ansatsu Kyoushitsu (Assassination Classroom), Kimura Masayoshi (木村 正義) was called Justice. His name, [Masayoshi, while usually read as Masayoshi, it is actually read as Seigi, which means justice](http://ansatsukyoshitsu.wikia.com/wiki/Masayoshi_Kimura#Plot).

My question is, why did he introduce himself as Tennouji Yuusha? His name is written as 天王寺 瑚太郎, while Yuusha is written as 勇者. How did he get Koutarou into Yuusha? Or is this all part of his Chuunibyou?

Comment: I don't think it is anything deep. Kotarou just likes to mess with people. Introducing himself with some weird name would be right his alley.